# Как организовать наследование в стилях приложения?

Tags: android, наследование, android-themes

В Android SDK < 21, например, нет возможности раскрасить статусбар. Или, например, необходимо задействовать определенный атрибут, сохранив все, работающие на более древних SDK. Ну, вот, возьмем, к примеру, тот же самый `colorPrimaryDark` для указания цвета статусбара.

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Как можно не писать `colorAccent` и `colorPrimary` в values-v21/styles.xml?

Вообщем, как сделать наследование стилей между styles.xml для разных API Level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А разве проблема актуальна с использованием [appcompat-v7](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7)? Вы можете задать цвет для статус бара, он просто не будет применяться на старых устройствах.

В общем случае проблема решается так: добавьте ещё один файл со стилями, например, `styles_base.xml`, куда положите "базовый" стиль, назвав его, например, `AppThemeBase`. Затем в Ваших `styles.xml`, которых будет несколько для разных версий (как у Вас сейчас сделано), добавьте стиль с одним и тем же названием `AppTheme`, который будет наследоваться от `AppThemeBase`

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppThemeBase">`

Таким образом, например, можно задавать разные атрибуты на разных версиях платформы, имея при этом набор каких-то общих элементов.